# A better way to download FTP contents to another server

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, ftp

I frequently have to move files from one server to another, when moving websites or when I have the need of a code package that is located on another server.

Currently I use the following commands:

```
wget -m --ftp-user=username --ftp-password=password ftp://ftp.domain.std/public_html
cp -rf ftp.domain.std/public_html/* .
cp -rf ftp.domain.std/public_html/.* .
```

This works fine, but I wonder if there is a method which will make the second and third line unnecessary?

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it. Write a script you can execute if two extra commands are too much.

Comment: why use ftp instead of rsync?

Comment: rsync? I think I'm not such a linux know-it-all as I look ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the `-nH --cut-dirs=1` parameters to skip the host directory (`-nH`) and cut away one level of directories (`--cut-dirs=1`)

(This may vary by wget version, this is from GNU wget.)

```
wget -nH --cut-dirs=1 -m --ftp-user=username --ftp-password=password ftp://ftp.domain.std/public_html
```